# Reading only the files in top directory in python

Tags: python, json, file, directory, readfile

I have a directory containing many .txt files, this same directory contains another directory containing .json files. I am trying to read the text files only and apply a function to them, then read the JSON files and apply a different function to these files. How do I access each file type individually instead of accessing all files and directories at once? Here is a basic code snippet to illustrate what I am trying to do.

```
textfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootdir, '*.txt'))
jsonfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootdir, '*.json'))

for f in textfiles:
    title = linecache.getline(f,1)
    titles = title[1:-1].split(',')#to convert what I read into list.
    do other stuff here...
    for item in titles:
        with open(f,"r") as fi:
            poems = json.load(fi)
        for fi in jsonfiles:
            with open(fi,"r") as file:
                poems = json.load(file)
            if(song["title"]==item):
                print(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `os.walk()` if all you need is the files in one directory.

You could use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to collect files of a specific type easily:

```
import glob
import os.path

textfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootdir, '*.txt'))
jsonfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootdir, 'subdue', '*.json'))
```

These globs would only find text 
 `rootdir` and the JSON files in a (named) subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but the JSON files are in a directory within the directory containing the .txt files. the JSONs are used in populate_graph  function which uses item (retrieved from .txt). maybe my brain is a little slow but I don't see how I can use glob in this context?

Comment: @ramez you could just use the path to the subdirectory then?

Comment: Sounds good, I changed my code based on your answer, but it seems to me that the only way access "item" is by nesting the loops. "item" is generated with every loop. any input on how to accomplish this without using nested loops? thank you kindly

Comment: @ramez rather than radically alter your question to use the code I proposed (and thus invalidating my answer) could you clarify what kind of content is in you text files and how it relates to the JSON files? I don't quite get how the two are related and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
onlytxtfiles = filter(onlyfiles, lambda(filename):filename.endswith('.txt'))
for fname in onlytxtfiles:
   ...
```

Fill in what you want to do in lieu of the `...` and let me know if you need further help.